# convert minimum spanning tree to list of indices using scipy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, data-science, sparse-matrix

If I have the following input and output graphs

```
 input graph             minimum spanning tree

     (0)                         (0)
    /   \                       /
   3     8                     3
  /       \                   /
(3)---5---(1)               (3)---5---(1)
  \       /                           /
   6     2                           2
    \   /                           /
     (2)                         (2)
```

... created using scipy.sparse.csgraph.minimum_spanning_tree:

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> from scipy.sparse.csgraph import minimum_spanning_tree
>>> X = csr_matrix([[0, 8, 0, 3],
...                 [0, 0, 2, 5],
...                 [0, 0, 0, 6],
...                 [0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> Tcsr = minimum_spanning_tree(X)
>>> Tcsr.toarray().astype(int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 2, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

How do I produce a simple list of indices? So:

```
[0,3,1,2]
```

Comment: Are you willing to use networkx?

Comment: My ideal answer would be to stay within scipy, but for the sake of moving forward with my life I will accept networkx

Comment: I think we need more information in order to answer this. What output would you like in the case that the minimum spanning tree is, well, a tree, with no natural sequential ordering? Are you looking for a depth-first ordering? breadth-first? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.sparse.csgraph` contains methods to list nodes in depth-first or breadth-first order:

```python
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import breadth_first_order, depth_first_order

print(breadth_first_order(Tcsr, i_start=0, directed=False, return_predecessors=False))
# [0 3 1 2]
print(depth_first_order(Tcsr, i_start=0, directed=False, return_predecessors=False))
# [0 3 1 2]
```

Since your tree has only a single branch, the two methods produce equivalent results. But for more general spanning trees, you should choose the method based on which traversal order you're interested in.